# Finding sum of a power series explicitly

Tags: power-series

I was wondering how to find the sum of the power series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {2^k{x^k}-2k}{x^k}$$

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(n^2-2^n)x^n$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes

Answer (score 2):

For the first, you can use the technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732627/formalizing-an-approach-to-the-sum-sum-k-0-inftykak) twice to get the $k^2$.  We have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac 1{1-x}\\
\frac d{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac d{dx}\frac 1{1-x}\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty xkx^{k-1}=x\frac 1{(1-x)^2}\\
\frac d{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty xkx^{k-1}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty xk^2x^{k-1}=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$

For the second, now that it has been updated, you can use the second line.

Comment: and then do you just subtract the sum of the second from the sum of the first? @rossmillikan

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: what do you get when you subtract it? @rossmillikan

Comment: I had missed a minus sign in the [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of++x%2F%281-x%29%5E2) output when I answered initially.  Fixed.  Can you subtract the fractions?

Comment: yes but it does not give the correct answer. the right answer is $$\frac{3x^2-x}{{(1-x)}^3}$$ @rossmillikan

Comment: When I answered the second term was $2^kx^k$.  Now you have $2kx^k$.  That is a different problem.  You can take the result in the middle of my answer  to get the second term.

Answer (score 0):

If $|z|<1$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k =\frac{1}{1-z} ~~~(1)$$
D.w.r.t. $z$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k z^k =\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}~~~~(2).$$
So $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [(2x)^k -2 k x^k]$$
By (1) and (2) we get
$$S=\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{5x^2-4x+1}{(1-2x)(1-x)^2}, ~if~ |x|<\frac{1}{2}.$$